Failed to connect to PieCloudDB using Navicat
I'm trying out PieCloudDB Database and now I want to connect PieCloudDB using Navicat, but it got stuck and connection failed. I used general connection mode, I think the problem might be with PieCloudDB, but I don't know how to troubleshoot. Any suggestion on it?

Please make sure to fill in '#'+ your virtual data warehouse id in Initial Database, if there is no problem with your connection information, first check whether the virtual data warehouse you are connected to is turned on or whether the automatic startup configuration is used in your PieCloudDB database.
If still not working, check whether the number of concurrent connections on the client reaches the upper limit.
